# Optical structure, vspace{...}?

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing

I am working on a very long proof.

I understand that `\newline` should be avoided to create optical structure.

Is `\vspace{...}` then the best i.e. most recommended way to give the proof some optical structure?

Comment: Perhaps you should start by defining "optical structure". I would never use `\vspace` in the text. As with `\newline` it is a sign that you are doing something wrong. Also often very long proofs are better split into lemmas and their proofs and then a concluding proof that uses the lemmas and make the overall conclusion. This is much nicer to read for the reader.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback. However, this is already a proof of a (not so relevant) lemma. It is very long because it is done by induction and there are 6 statements to show. Right now it is 15 pages but it is quite easy to follow. I dont want to split it up because this gives it even more relevance which it really does not deserve...

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to answer your question given the information provided. For formal proofs people often use algorithm or specific proof environments where newlines are significant like laying out programming language code. If you mean a textual classical proof then normal text layout for the document should be in force and with no example impossible to guess why you would need forced line breaks or explicit vertical space.

Comment: Have you ever considered using `\paragraph{Case 3: $n$ divisible by 37.}` or similar. The `\paragraph` command is very underused, I use it a lot when rewriting manuscripts to get rid of long lists, structure for proofs. Jut be aware that one cannot start a `proof` with `\pagrahraph` for technical reasons.

Comment: I was not aware of `\paragraph` and will try it out! Many thanks.

Comment: I think I will go with `\paragraph`. But I have one last question regarding this: When using `\paragraph` the font is different than the font of my paper. (It looks like Arial or so). Is this the intended effect of `\paragraph`?

Comment: It is not arial by default so we don't know what your document is doing. Normally it is bold. `\paragraph` is the level below `\subsubsection`. Often not used at all. Depending on your document you can easily change the font and spacing for it. Remember that since it in runin it is a good idea to end the text by punctuation.